# How can I list app engine datastore parent values with python?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Not sure if on the title I should have said parent values or ancestors, but here is what I am trying to do.

I am learning to use Python in Google App Engine. While I am reviewing the content of [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore) in the Guestbook tutorial, I was wondering if I could enhance it by listing all possible guestbooks created.

To give a bit of context, this is how the sample code works. The application renders a page that allows you to create a guestbook entry, as well as switching/creating new guestbooks for current or future entries. I thought it would be simple to add the ability to list all currently stored guestbooks to dynamically generate a list of links to see each one.

I thought this was very simple, but I am trying and I can't figure it out. How do I query the datastore to give me a list of all the "guestbooks" available so I can build the links dynamically? If the guestbook is called guestbook_2 the url looks like this "?guestbook_name=guestbook_2".

Here is the code of the application (I added the string "INSERT LIST HERE" where I want to addd the list of links I just mentioned):

```
import cgi
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

import webapp2


MAIN_PAGE_FOOTER_TEMPLATE = """\
<form action="/sign?%s" method="post">
  <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
</form>

<hr>

<form>Guestbook name (you can create your own guestbook here):
  <input value="%s" name="guestbook_name">
  <input type="submit" value="switch">
</form>

<a href="%s">%s</a>

<br><br>
List of guestbooks: %s

  </body>
</html>
"""

DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME = 'default_guestbook'


# We set a parent key on the 'Greetings' to ensure that they are all in the same
# entity group. Queries across the single entity group will be consistent.
# However, the write rate should be limited to ~1/second.

def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME):
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
    return ndb.Key('Guestbook', guestbook_name)


class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual Guestbook entry with author, content, and date."""
    author = ndb.UserProperty()
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.write('<html><body>')
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)

        # Ancestor Queries, as shown here, are strongly consistent with the High
        # Replication Datastore. Queries that span entity groups are eventually
        # consistent. If we omitted the ancestor from this query there would be
        # a slight chance that Greeting that had just been written would not
        # show up in a query.
        greetings_query = Greeting.query(
            ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

        for greeting in greetings:
            if greeting.author:
                self.response.write(
                        '<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())
            else:
                self.response.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
            self.response.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' %
                                cgi.escape(greeting.content))

        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'


        # Write the submission form and the footer of the page
        sign_query_params = urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name})
        self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_FOOTER_TEMPLATE %
                            (sign_query_params, 
                            cgi.escape(guestbook_name),
                             url, 
                             url_linktext,
                             "INSERT LIST HERE"
                             ))


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        # We set the same parent key on the 'Greeting' to ensure each Greeting
        # is in the same entity group. Queries across the single entity group
        # will be consistent. However, the write rate to a single entity group
        # should be limited to ~1/second.
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = users.get_current_user()

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
        greeting.put()

        query_params = {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}
        self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook),
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the guestbook name somewhere, or the easiest thing is you can fetch all the Greeting's key to get the parent, something like

```
guestbooks = [greeting.key().parent().name() for greeting in Greeting.all(keys_only=True)]
```

Comment: I think this is probably the answer that I was looking for. However, I must be greener in Python than I thought. Can you give me a bit more direction on how to approach this? I know that I declare the variable guestbooks like you suggested and then I need to use it where I want to display its value(s). I am just not clear on how exactly to do it. I know I am close.

Comment: Just to be clear, I tried adding the "guestbooks" variable inside the "get" method of the MainPage class. I also tried in other places, but I get different types of errors when I try doing that. I am not posting the errors here because I want to approach it correctly instead of by trial and error. I feel like I almost get it. Just not quite there yet. Thank you for your advice and help.